# git add and commit are suddenly extremely slow, what could cause this

Tags: git

I'm using Cmder on Windows 10

I've created a new Drupal 8 project with composer.

I've ran these commands:

```
git init
git add -A
git commit
```

The add and commit were both extremely slow.

Add took 5+ minutes to add everything.

Commit took about 2-3 minutes to commit everything.

This has never been an issue before, but it is the first time I commit a new project with Cmder.

I've googled a bit, but couldn't find anything relevant.

Could my console be causing this? Or is something else wrong?

I've done this in the past for other new projects (on my old PC) with Git Bash and running git add -A on a new project took like 20 seconds give or take, now it literally took 10+ minutes

Comment: Maybe you installed an anti-virus application lately?
Can you try it with Git Bash for performance comparison?

Answer (score 0):

maybe the problem is maybe you use some package managers and this makes git job so harder because it goes to every folders and depencencies and check does it change or not ... and you must ignore them in `.gitignore` file